# regex question - Find a password like word in a sentence

Tags: regex

Regex is `\b(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}\b`
Sentence is

> This sentence has a GoodNight13 word

I am expecting to find only `GoodNight13`, but I am also picking up `sentence`.

How can I avoid finding `sentence`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only match `A-Z` `a-z` and `\d` instead of using `.*`, and when asserting exclude what you want first from the leading character class first before matching it.

```
\b(?=[a-z\d]*[A-Z])(?=[A-Z\d]*[a-z])(?=[A-Za-z]*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r5M04a/1)